# display chinese characters in android

Tags: android

I am trying to pass in data (from a server) using PHP and the data consists of Chinese characters. I am trying to parse the data using the JSON parser I did manage to retrieve the data but the data (in Chinese) appears as `???`. can some one tell me what went wrong?

Below is my parser:

```
// function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```

As seen on my logcat.

```
11-09 07:18:53.939: D/Single Product Details(570): {"success":1,"search":[{"tel1":"67546498","generalEmail":"anderlab01@yahoo.com.sg","contactEmail":"jeff1285@hotmail.com","lineOfBusiness":"??????????? Manufacture,Import\/Export","postCode1":"738733","companyNameEng":" ANDER LAB PTE LTD ","repName1Eng":"Li Jianfu","address1":"Blk 20 Woodlands Link #04-40","fax1":"67544092","repName1Chi":"???","url":"www.bosun.com.sg"}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

my db is already default to utf8, Encounter the same problem.

After adding the usual meta tag "", the problem is still there.

Then I created a dedicated connection.php to ensure all communication with mysql is charset utf8, note there is no **"-"** in utf8 in mysqli_set_charset($bd, 'utf8')  !

**Connection.php**

```
<?php
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
    $mysql_user = "username";
    $mysql_password = "password";
    $mysql_database = "dbname";
    $prefix = "";
    $bd = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
    mysqli_select_db($bd, $mysql_database) or die("Could not select database");
    if(!mysqli_set_charset($bd, 'utf8'))  {
        exit() ;
    }

?>
```

Here's an example of sending retrieving data.

```
<?php

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('connection.php');

        enter code here

    //Create query
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM subject";
    $result = mysqli_query($bd, $qry);
    //  other stuff
?>
```

Comment: example seems empty!!

Answer (score 1):

Solved. You need to encoding your POST in utf8 .

```
 if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"utf-8")); <------ utf8
```

Comment: It should be the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String test(){
String testResult= "";
try {
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://xxxxx");//edit url removed.
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
    if(!obj.isNull("title")){
        testResult= obj.getString("title");
        Log.d("Test","Test1:"+ testResult);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return testResult;//
```

}

Take help from this code.. It will surely help u..
Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide code snippet how you retrieve the data. Here is my guess with assumption the source charset is UTF-8, replace with your source encoding accordingly.

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

str is your json string.

Update: Seems like you retrieve with `iso-8859-1`, thus try to update your code to `UTF-8`.

Note: The character encoding of JSON text is always Unicode. UTF-8 is the only encoding that makes sense on the wire, but UTF-16 and UTF-32 are also permitted ([source](http://www.json.org/fatfree.html)).

Comment: I will try it out. Thanks. I have another question to ask.. when I run my .php on the web, the words are also in "???". Do I have to do certain encoding also? to show the utf-8..

Comment: Make sure the php file is saved in UTF-8 and try to set your render html page with `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`